# how flag variable let go back the main menu in this code?

Tags: java

```
public class FlagPr {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean flag = true;
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Are you a human being or a robot? : ");
            System.out.println("1. a human being");
            System.out.println("2. a robot");
            int menu = sc.nextInt();
            switch (menu) {
            case 1: {
                System.out.println("What type of human being are you?");
                System.out.println("1. Good");
                System.out.println("2. Bad");
                System.out.println("3. Back to main");
                int select = sc.nextInt();
                if (select == 1) {
                    System.out.println("ARE YOU SURE");
                } else if (select == 2) {
                    System.out.println("YOU MUST BE THE SHIT ONE");
                } else if (select == 3) {
                    flag = true;

                }

            }
            default:
                break;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

I was studying about making a small menu with Java and came cross the fact that the flag variable can lean me go back to the main menu, but I cannot understand the workflow of the flag variable.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider this flag variable as a sentinel.

You should start out with this `boolean flag = false;` instead of setting it to true.

When your user selects option 3, *then* you set the flat to true.

At the end of your while loop, you would do a conditional check on the value of the flag.

Example:

```java
if(flag == true) {
    // code to return to main menu
}
```

Doing so allows your switch statement to do actions and *not* have to display the menu options again to the user.

The user would enter an option, the switch statement would occur, code in the cases would execute, then the while loop would continue again.